# SQlite3 query all t1.rows that are not connected to one t2.row via any t3.rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 and have three tables.
The `user_permissions` connects `users` with certain `elements` and permission values (0/1).

Given one element id, I need to find all users that have either no permissions on that element (no record in user_permissions with user_id+element_id) or have can_read=1 or can_edit=1 but not can_manage=1.

I tried about a billion queries now and can't figure it out..

Is this possible with SQlite3?

```
users:
id, name

user_permissions:
user_id, element_id, can_read, can_edit, can_manage

elements:
id, title
```

Comment: Did you try [not exists](https://dbfiddle.uk/MH-lTAOF) ?

Comment: apparently not … thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT * from users u
LEFT JOIN user_permissions up ON up.user_id = u.id AND up.element_id = @desired_element
WHERE up.user_id IS NULL 
OR ((up.can_read = 1 OR up.can_edit = 1) AND NOT up.can_manage = 1)
```

With LEFT JOIN, `WHERE up.user_id IS NULL` will include users without any permission for that element.

Comment: Edited to correct (up.can_read = 1 OR up.can_edit = 1)